# Маршрут проезда по двум точкам в виде координат

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

```
ymaps.route([
 {type: 'wayPoint', point: [lat1,lon1] },
 {type: 'wayPoint', point: [lat2,lon2] }
 ]).then(
 function (route) {
// console.info(route);
// console.info(route.editor);
 },
 function (error) {
 console.info(error);
 }
 );
```

Хочу из объекта route вытащить список `double[]`
спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
ymaps.route([
    'Москва, метро Крылатское', 'Москва, метро Молодежная'
]).then
(
    function (route) {
        var coords = [];

        // Получаем первый маршрут
        var way = route.getPaths().get(0);

        // Маршрут состоит из сегментов
        var segments = way.getSegments();

        for (var i = 0; i < segments.length; i++) {
            coords.push(segments[i].getCoordinates());
        }

        //coords : [ [lat, lng], .. ]

    },
    function (error) {
        console.info(error);
    }
);
```